# Can anyone help me to resolve the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html

```js
window.onload = function what() {
  var a = document.getElementById("abc");
  a.innerHTML = 'hi';
};
```

```html
<div id="editor">
  <p id="abc">Class </p>{ public void add(int a, int b){ int sum=a+b; } }
</div>
```

Comment: please refer to this code below... typo mistake in the above code...
<div id="editor">
<p id="abc">Class </p>{
public void add(int a, int b){
int sum=a+b;
}
}</div>

<script >
window.onload = function what(){
var a=document.getElementById("abc");
a.innerHTML = 'hi';
};
</script>

Comment: Don't post code in comments, you can edit your question

Comment: @arpitgupta Please edit the question with correct code.

Comment: Well the code you posted works, so something is missing here

Comment: That code has no issues so it is related to something else that you are not showing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: @epascarello correct. My assumption is that the `"abc"` element is not created when `onload` happens.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById()` either returns a DOM node or `null`, based on whether an element with the given **id** exists in the HTML document.

Since your error message says *"Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of `null`"*, it means that no element with id "abc" was found.